# Share selected binding image from json

Tags: c#, json, image, uwp

I have some collection of image data contained in json. I wish that the selected image on a page can be shared. How to?

XAML:

```
<Grid Background="#FF302A2A"
        d:DataContext="{Binding Groups[0].Items[0], Source={d:DesignData Source=/DataModel/TemplesData.json, Type=data:TemplesDataSource}}">

        <Grid x:Name="gridAtas" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="0" Margin="0,0,10,17" DataContext="{Binding Item}">

            <AppBarButton x:Name="shareBtn" Margin="0,0,30,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Icon="ReShare" Foreground="White" Click="shareBtn_Click" />
        </Grid>

        <Grid x:Name="gridContent" Grid.Row="1">
            <FlipView ItemsSource="{Binding Group.Items}" SelectedItem="{Binding Item, Mode=TwoWay}" Foreground="{x:Null}">
                <FlipView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid x:Name="content" Margin="70,0,0,0">

                            <Image x:Name="photo" Grid.Column="0" Margin="20,0,10,10" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Source="{Binding ImagePath}" />

                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </FlipView.ItemTemplate>
            </FlipView>
        </Grid>
```

Code:

```
private async void navigationHelper_LoadState(object sender, LoadStateEventArgs e)
    {
        var item = await TemplesDataSource.GetItemAsync((String)e.NavigationParameter);
        var group = await TemplesDataSource.GetGroupByItemAsync(item);
        this.DefaultViewModel["Group"] = group;
        this.DefaultViewModel["Item"] = item;
    }


    private void shareBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

How is a way to share the image selected?

Comment: What do you mean by "Share" ? Generate an url or save to local storage or uploaded to other services (google drive, microsoft onedrive, dropbox etc)

Comment: i mean share on social media, like as facebook, twitter, email, etc

Comment: Each social media has it own way to share. It can be done with just javascript. For example, for Facebook, you can read this article: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/raj1979/how-to-use-facebook-share-functionality-in-Asp-Net/

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft provides Inbuilt Share data option through [DataTransferManager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/app-to-app/share-data).

All guidelines for sharing are provided [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465251.aspx)

There is a [ShareSource](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/ShareSource) sample on Microsoft GitHub page on how to do this.

You are looking to share Image in Particular. So look for [This](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/master/Samples/ShareSource/cs/ShareImage.xaml.cs)

I am not posting the code here since there will be too much code to post and its better you download the sample and try along.

Answer (score 0):

@AVK have a good answer.And I have a different answer.You can use the Image of cloud storage and upload your image to the cloud and it can be share as a url.

The image of cloud storage can use [oneDrive](http://www.windowscentral.com/new-onedrive-app-windows-10-pc) SDK to upload as @Jacky say.

I hope the answer can help you.